# 'n' in my vim waits a short time before searching for next

Tags: linux, vim, plugins

It's like I have an nmap to np and one to n and it's waiting to see if I press the p or not before actually searching, but there are no mappings in my vim.rc for that.

Other questions said that the output of :map is helpful, but I can't see anything that helps me.

I think it might be a plugin causing this behaviour.

What could be causing this?

Here is the output of my :map

```
n  y<C-G>      *@:call setreg(v:register, <SNR>64_recall())<CR>
n  <C-E>         :CtrlP<CR>
n  <C-H>       * <C-W>h
x  <Tab>         <Plug>snipMateVisual
s  <Tab>         <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
n  <Tab>         :SyntasticReset<CR>
n  <NL>        * <C-W>j
n  <C-K>       * <C-W>k
n  <C-L>       * <C-W>l
n  <C-N>       * :bnext<CR>
n  <C-P>       * :bprev<CR>
n  <C-S>         :w <CR> :SyntasticCheck<CR>
n  <C-W>         :w<CR>
v  <C-_>9        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>9
no <C-_>9        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>9
v  <C-_>8        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>8
no <C-_>8        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>8
v  <C-_>7        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>7
no <C-_>7        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>7
v  <C-_>6        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>6
no <C-_>6        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>6
v  <C-_>5        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>5
no <C-_>5        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>5
v  <C-_>4        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>4
no <C-_>4        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>4
v  <C-_>3        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>3
no <C-_>3        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>3
v  <C-_>2        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>2
no <C-_>2        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>2
v  <C-_>1        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>1
no <C-_>1        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>1
   <C-_>ca       <Plug>TComment_<C-_>ca
   <C-_>cc       <Plug>TComment_<C-_>cc
   <C-_>s        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>s
   <C-_>n        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>n
   <C-_>a        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>a
   <C-_>b        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>b
   <C-_>i        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>i
   <C-_>r        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>r
   <C-_><Space>   <Plug>TComment_<C-_><Space>
   <C-_>p        <Plug>TComment_<C-_>p
v  <C-_><C-_>    <Plug>TComment_<C-_><C-_>
no <C-_><C-_>    <Plug>TComment_<C-_><C-_>
o  %           * v:<C-U>call <SNR>68_Match_wrapper('',1,'o') <CR>
v  %           * :<C-U>call <SNR>68_Match_wrapper('',1,'v') <CR>m'gv``
n  %           * :<C-U>call <SNR>68_Match_wrapper('',1,'n') <CR>
   ,_s           <Plug>TComment_,_s
   ,_n           <Plug>TComment_,_n
   ,_a           <Plug>TComment_,_a
   ,_b           <Plug>TComment_,_b
   ,_r           <Plug>TComment_,_r
x  ,_i           <Plug>TComment_,_i
   ,_<Space>     <Plug>TComment_,_<Space>
   ,_p           <Plug>TComment_,_p
x  ,__           <Plug>TComment_,__
nos,__           <Plug>TComment_,__
n  ,ff           :%s/.\/src\/app/\./g<CR>
n  ,js           :set ft=javascript<CR>
n  ,u            :e #<CR>
n  ,R            :%s/console\.log/\/\/ console\.log/g <CR>
n  ,C            :%s/\/\/ console\.log/console\.log/g <CR>
n  ,pu           :PluginUpdate<CR>
n  ,pc           :PluginClean<CR>
n  ,pi           :PluginInstall<CR>
   ,g          * :!!<CR>
n  ,pa           "*p
n  ,gg           :qa<CR>
n  ,gc           :bw<CR>
n  ,sh           :set ft=sh<CR>
n  ,bl           :ls<CR>
n  ,.            zt
n  ,W            :StripWhitespace<CR>
n  ,w            :ToggleWhitespace<CR>
n  ,p            "*p
n  ,d            :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
n  ,ss           :Ng build<CR>
n  ,hs           :SStylesheet<CR>
n  ,hc           :SComponent<CR>
n  ,ht           :STemplate<CR>
n  ,vs           :VStylesheet<CR>
n  ,vc           :VComponent<CR>
n  ,vt           :VTemplate<CR>
n  ,es           :EStylesheet<CR>
n  ,ec           :EComponent<CR>
n  ,et           :ETemplate<CR>
n  ;           * :
x  S             <Plug>VSurround
o  [%          * v:<C-U>call <SNR>68_MultiMatch("bW", "o") <CR>
v  [%            <Esc>[%m'gv``
n  [%          * :<C-U>call <SNR>68_MultiMatch("bW", "n") <CR>
o  ]%          * v:<C-U>call <SNR>68_MultiMatch("W",  "o") <CR>
v  ]%            <Esc>]%m'gv``
n  ]%          * :<C-U>call <SNR>68_MultiMatch("W",  "n") <CR>
v  a%            <Esc>[%v]%
n  cS            <Plug>CSurround
n  cs            <Plug>Csurround
n  ds            <Plug>Dsurround
v  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
x  gS            <Plug>VgSurround
o  g%          * v:<C-U>call <SNR>68_Match_wrapper('',0,'o') <CR>
v  g%          * :<C-U>call <SNR>68_Match_wrapper('',0,'v') <CR>m'gv``
n  g%          * :<C-U>call <SNR>68_Match_wrapper('',0,'n') <CR>
x  g>            <Plug>TComment_Comment
n  g>b           <Plug>TComment_Commentb
n  g>c           <Plug>TComment_Commentc
n  g>            <Plug>TComment_Comment
x  g<            <Plug>TComment_Uncomment
n  g<b           <Plug>TComment_Uncommentb
n  g<c           <Plug>TComment_Uncommentc
n  g<            <Plug>TComment_Uncomment
x  gc            <Plug>TComment_gc
n  gcb           <Plug>TComment_gcb
n  gcc           <Plug>TComment_gcc
n  gc9c          <Plug>TComment_gc9c
n  gc9           <Plug>TComment_gc9
n  gc8c          <Plug>TComment_gc8c
n  gc8           <Plug>TComment_gc8
n  gc7c          <Plug>TComment_gc7c
n  gc7           <Plug>TComment_gc7
n  gc6c          <Plug>TComment_gc6c
n  gc6           <Plug>TComment_gc6
n  gc5c          <Plug>TComment_gc5c
n  gc5           <Plug>TComment_gc5
n  gc4c          <Plug>TComment_gc4c
n  gc4           <Plug>TComment_gc4
n  gc3c          <Plug>TComment_gc3c
n  gc3           <Plug>TComment_gc3
n  gc2c          <Plug>TComment_gc2c
n  gc2           <Plug>TComment_gc2
n  gc1c          <Plug>TComment_gc1c
n  gc1           <Plug>TComment_gc1
n  gc            <Plug>TComment_gc
o  ic            <Plug>TComment_ic
v  ic            <Plug>TComment_ic
   null          <Plug>(ctrlp)
n  ySS           <Plug>YSsurround
n  ySs           <Plug>YSsurround
n  yss           <Plug>Yssurround
n  yS            <Plug>YSurround
n  ys            <Plug>Ysurround
s  <S-Tab>       <Plug>snipMateBack
v  <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis * :<C-U>call netrw#BrowseXVis()<CR>
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#BrowseX(expand((exists("g:netrw_gx")? g:netrw_gx : '<cfile>')),netrw#CheckIfRemote())<CR>
v  <Plug>VgSurround * :<C-U>call <SNR>72_opfunc(visualmode(),visualmode() ==# 'V' ? 0 : 1)<CR>
v  <Plug>VSurround * :<C-U>call <SNR>72_opfunc(visualmode(),visualmode() ==# 'V' ? 1 : 0)<CR>
n  <Plug>YSurround * :<C-U>set opfunc=<SNR>72_opfunc2<CR>g@
n  <Plug>Ysurround * :<C-U>set opfunc=<SNR>72_opfunc<CR>g@
n  <Plug>YSsurround * :<C-U>call <SNR>72_opfunc2(v:count1)<CR>
n  <Plug>Yssurround * :<C-U>call <SNR>72_opfunc(v:count1)<CR>
n  <Plug>CSurround * :<C-U>call <SNR>72_changesurround(1)<CR>
n  <Plug>Csurround * :<C-U>call <SNR>72_changesurround()<CR>
n  <Plug>Dsurround * :<C-U>call <SNR>72_dosurround(<SNR>72_inputtarget())<CR>
n  <Plug>SurroundRepeat * .
x  <Plug>snipMateVisual * :<C-U>call <SNR>69_grab_visual()<CR>gv"_c
s  <Plug>snipMateBack * <Esc>a<C-R>=snipMate#BackwardsSnippet()<CR>
s  <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger * <Esc>a<C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<CR>
n  <SNR>64_:   * :<C-U><C-R>=v:count ? v:count : ''<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(10) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),9,'')<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(9) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),8,'')<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(8) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),7,'')<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(7) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),6,'')<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(6) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),5,'')<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(5) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),4,'')<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(4) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),3,'')<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(3) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),2,'')<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(2) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),1,'')<CR>
   <Plug>BufTabLine.Go(1) * :exe 'b'.get(buftabline#user_buffers(),0,'')<CR>
n  <Plug>TComment_gc9c * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc9c<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gc8c * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc8c<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gc7c * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc7c<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gc6c * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc6c<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gc5c * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc5c<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gc4c * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc4c<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gc3c * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc3c<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gc2c * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc2c<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gc1c * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc1c<CR>g@
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_>9 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 9)<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_>9 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 9)<CR>
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_>8 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 8)<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_>8 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 8)<CR>
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_>7 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 7)<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_>7 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 7)<CR>
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_>6 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 6)<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_>6 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 6)<CR>
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_>5 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 5)<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_>5 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 5)<CR>
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_>4 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 4)<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_>4 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 4)<CR>
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_>3 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 3)<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_>3 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 3)<CR>
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_>2 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 2)<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_>2 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 2)<CR>
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_>1 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 1)<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_>1 * :call tcomment#SetOption("count", 1)<CR>
n  <Plug>TComment_gC * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gC<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gc * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gc<CR>g@
x  <Plug>TComment_gc * :TCommentMaybeInline<CR>
n  <Plug>TComment_gcb * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gcb<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_gcc * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_gcc<CR>g@$
   <Plug>TComment_ic * :<C-U>call tcomment#TextObjectInlineComment()<CR>
x  <Plug>TComment_Comment * :<C-U>if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | '<,'>TCommentMaybeInline!<CR>
n  <Plug>TComment_Commentb * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_Commentb<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_Commentc * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_Commentc<CR>g@$
n  <Plug>TComment_Commentl * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_Commentl<CR>g@$
n  <Plug>TComment_Comment * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_Comment<CR>g@
x  <Plug>TComment_Uncomment * :<C-U>if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | call tcomment#SetOption("mode_extra", "U") | '<,'>TCommentMaybeInline<CR>
n  <Plug>TComment_Uncommentb * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_Uncommentb<CR>g@
n  <Plug>TComment_Uncommentc * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_Uncommentc<CR>g@$
n  <Plug>TComment_Uncomment * :<C-U>call tcomment#ResetOption() | if v:count > 0 | call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count) | endif | let w:tcommentPos = getpos(".") |set opfunc=TCommentOpFunc_Uncomment<CR>g@
   <Plug>TComment_,_s * :TCommentAs <C-R>=&ft<CR>_
   <Plug>TComment_,_n * :TCommentAs <C-R>=&ft<CR><Space>
   <Plug>TComment_,_a * :TCommentAs<Space>
   <Plug>TComment_,_b * :TCommentBlock<CR>
   <Plug>TComment_,_r * :TCommentRight<CR>
x  <Plug>TComment_,_i * :TCommentInline<CR>
   <Plug>TComment_,_<Space> * :TComment<Space>
   <Plug>TComment_,_p * vip:TComment<CR>
x  <Plug>TComment_,__ * :TCommentMaybeInline<CR>
nos<Plug>TComment_,__ * :TComment<CR>
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_>ca * :<C-U>call tcomment#SetOption("as", input("Comment as: ", &filetype, "customlist,tcomment#Complete"))<CR>
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_>cc * :<C-U>call tcomment#SetOption("count", v:count1)<CR>
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_>s * :TCommentAs <C-R>=&ft<CR>_
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_>n * :TCommentAs <C-R>=&ft<CR><Space>
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_>a * :TCommentAs<Space>
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_>b * :TCommentBlock<CR>
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_>i * v:TCommentInline mode=I#<CR>
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_>r * :TCommentRight<CR>
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_><Space> * :TComment<Space>
   <Plug>TComment_<C-_>p * m`vip:TComment<CR>``
v  <Plug>TComment_<C-_><C-_> * :TCommentMaybeInline<CR>
no <Plug>TComment_<C-_><C-_> * :TComment<CR>
n  <Plug>(ctrlp) * :<C-U>CtrlP<CR>
   <F2>          :echo 'Current time is ' . strftime('%c')<CR>
   <F10>         :tabm +1<CR>
   <F9>          :tabm -1<CR>
   «           * :
   ©           * :
   ª           * :
   ò           * :
   ã           * :
   ç           * :
   î           * :
   ô           * :
   è           * :
   í           * :
```

Comment: We can do better than just `:map` to debug your mapping. Please use `:verbose nmap n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mapping is active (also) in normal mode and makes Vim wait for additional characters after `n` (to check whether you actually wanted the `null` mapping):

```
null          <Plug>(ctrlp)
```

As you've already commented, this is caused by the following, presumably an attempt to disable the CtrlP mappings:

```
let g:ctrlp_map = 'null'
```

To do this correctly, configure a dummy mapping that starts with `<Plug>` as these will never match typed characters (cp. `:help <Plug>`):

```
let g:ctrlp_map = '<Plug>DisabledCtrlP'
```